# Display image within PHP code

Tags: php

First of all, I'd like to let you know that i know "Zero" about PHP. So I hope someone can help me with this.

I want to display an image with link within the PHP code. This is the code I have on the website:

```
<?php
// PHP variables below must be surrounded in quotes and line end with semi-colon. Set desired values by replacing the name, number or address inside the double quotes with the desired value.

// Set the contact phone #
$contactPhone = "123-456-7890";

// Set the contact email
$contactEmail = "email@gmail.com";

// Set the first thru third lines of the physical address
$contactAddress[] = "My Department";
$contactAddress[] = "1234 Main Street";
$contactAddress[] = "My City, TX 12346";

$contactAddress[] = "<br /><b>Hours of Operation:</b>";
$contactAddress[] = "7:30 AM - 4:30 PM<br />";

// do not modify this
$contactAddress = implode('<br />', $contactAddress);

?>
```

I'd like to add a Facebook icon with link underneath the "Hours of Operation" [This is what i would like for it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcTf5.jpg)

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
**SO is not** a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service
___We fix your attempts, we do not write your code___

Comment: You could benefit from a good HTML tutorial. For now keep in mind that the HTML hyperlink is `<a href='<url>'>` and the image is `<img src='<source URL>' />` . You should read more about those 2 tags.

Answer (score 0):

You use HTML code in PHP for like this.

```
echo"<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/mypage\"><img src=\"images/facebookicon.png\" /></a>";
```

If you didn't understand that, you must learn html before php.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. But it's adding the image at the top of all the information instead of at the bottom. How do i keep it on the bottom?

Comment: You must look to css. U can keep it everywhere with css. U can see this site for everythink about css. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp